# C# Forcing static fields

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, static

I suppose this is an unusual use case. But I've run into it a few times now.

Is it possible to force all inherited classes to have public static variables that are defined in the child class?

Aka:

```
APacket.ID   = 0; // Abstract parent class, has static ID variable (0)
PacketPos.ID = 1; // Inherits from APacket, has static ID variable (1)
PacketVel.ID = 2; // Inherits from APacket, has static ID variable (2)
```

I want all my network packet classes to have unique and public static **ID** and **Length** variables.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: No. Inheritance is about controlling _instantiated_ objects. Static is explicitly about non-instantiated entities.

Comment: @gunr2171 Static members *are* inherited though.  There's just no virtual dispatch of static members, and as a result there is no support for polymorphism of static members.

Comment: I think this question is not duplicate. The OP is asking about unique static variables in derived classes with same name

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I feel as though forcing static members should be supported. It would be quite useful in numerous situations.